# Can you look sample a texture in a vertex shader?

Tags: hlsl, direct3d11

In shader model 3.0, I'm pretty sure this was a *no* but I want to ask this anyway,

In shader model 5.0, can you sample a texture in a vertex shader?

If I want to make large amounts of supplementary information available per-vertex, what are my options?

Edit:
Apparently it *is* possible to do a Vertex Texture Fetch, as done [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter18.html), but when I try it in my hlsl shader model 5 program, I get the error

> error X4532: cannot map expression to vs_5_0 instruction set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sampling a texture from a vertex shader is very easily done in Shader Model 5.0, using [operator[ unint2 ]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff471561%28VS.85%29.aspx) on any `Texture2D` object.

So for example, `tex0` is a `Texture2D` object in a shader model 5 hlsl program:

```
Texture2D tex0 : register( t0 );

// in a vertex shader program
uint2 pos_xy = { 0, 1 } ;
texelColor = tex0[ pos_xy ] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

YES, but you must use `SampleLevel` to sample. You can also load values directly from the texture using `mytexture[xy_coord]` or `texture.Load(...)` which provides values without 'sampling' (e.g. bilinear interpolation).

You can sample a texture in a vertex shader using the `SampleLevel` function, where you must also specify the mip-mapping level that you want to sample at. You can imagine that the `Sample` function uses the `SampleLevel` function internally, with the added benefit that the mip-mapping level is selected for you automatically by taking local derivatives of the texture coordinate lookup in screen space (this allows the GPU to select which mip level to use).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509699(v=vs.85).aspx